# Python script unable to receive input from Java

Tags: python, java

I am quite aware that this might be more of a Java/Python problem but it's on the RasPi and I also don't know if Java or Python is the problem.

So here is the situation:

I have a python script which is run by a Java Program with Runtime exec.

The two programs communicate quite simply with each other if the java Programm sends "go" the python script does something, once its done it returns "done"

```
while true:
    raw_input('')
    #do something
    print('done')
```

Running this in command line works fine, it does just what its supposed to.

And the java program Opens input and output streams from the Process.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python test1.py "+number1+" "+number2);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new OutputStreamReader(p.getOutputStream()));
```

So here is where it gets messy.

If I run this and check for the input stream to be ready, it won't be, it will never be ready so I can't read from it. If I remove the line `raw_input('')` the input stream in Java will be readable but I just can't communicate with the script anymore.

I am pretty sure it's something very little which I just don't see! 
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run from Java, the python interpreter knows that it's not connected to an interactive terminal and shuts down the in/out that you're using.  Try using the `-i` flag to python to force interactive mode.

To use that flag, I think you'll also have to use `ProcessBuilder` in Java rather than `exec` as you've done, but you might be able to make it work with `exec` too.

Comment: The `-i` flag changed nothing. I found out that, as soon as the python script is in a blocking call (like `raw_input` or `time.sleep`) I can't read the output anymore even the lines that were printed before that.

Comment: I think you have multiple problems then. I still think you need the `-i` flag, but you may also need to flush your buffers on either or both sides when you write.

Comment: Thank you! I flushed in Java but not stdout in python, doing that solved the issue!